# compression a compound Variable with swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I wrote this little piece of code, but I have the impression that it is not optimal, indeed as the field variable is in get only : I can not directly change it .... but I am junior : so I would be delighted if someone has a better idea :) thank you .

```
let keyword = ["potatoes","garlic"]
var field: String {
        var element = ""
        keyword.forEach {
            element +=  "&field=" + $0
        }
        return element
    }
```

a shorter code coming from professionalswift developper :)

Comment: If you are trying to create a url query string then you should use `URLComponents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would be better

```
let keyword = ["potatoes","garlic"]
var field: String {
    return keyword.map { "&field=\($0)"}.joined()
}
```